# Algorithm which calculates the greatest sum lesser than or equal to N, using exactly one array element for M arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Suppose that we are given the following set of arrays, each of which can have a different number of members:

```
13 2 17 5

2 3 4 5

6 1 70 9

3 90 2 25
```

And a limit `N = 72`. Is there an algorithm to calculate the sum that is closest to `N`, keeping in mind that we must use exactly one element from each array?

Update, I've gotten as far as finishing the input, which is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main() {
std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
int T,B,N;
std::cin>>T>>B>>N;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr;
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
  int temp;
   std::cin>>temp;
   std::vector<int> row;
   for(int i=0;i<temp;i++)
   {
       row.push_back(0);
   }
   arr.push_back(row);
}
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<arr.at(i).size();j++)
    {
        int temp;
        std::cin>>temp;
        arr.at(i).at(j)=temp;
    }
}

return 0; }
```

Comment: Have you tried any ideas so far?

Comment: I would reason to assume you'd subtract the largest possible number from each array from `N`, and whatever is left over, you know is the closest? At first thought that works, but I'm not sure if it will break in any case.

Comment: Is `N = 72` an upper bound or can you go above it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is a bit broad as posed. Yes, of course there is an algorithm to do this, but SO is about helping you with specific issues in your code rather than just giving you the algorithm. If you post a [mcve] showing your attempt, you'll be much more likely to get a concrete answer. It's OK to ask a language-agnostic algorithm question, but it should still have an attempt (and you can drop the language tag then). Thanks.

Comment: @Rietty I think you mean "subtract the smallest number in each array from the array and from N", in order to reduce the problem.

Comment: I'll follow up with the code shortly.

Comment: Basically, im stuck at even entering the data, I'm guessing I could use a vector of vector, so the main vector holds all of the vectors with the sets of integers?

Comment: A vector of vectors would work. For efficient computation you might want to try dynamic programming.

Comment: @Rietty That won't always be correct. For example, if we have `{{1, 7}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}}` and `N = 10` Your algorithm gives `{7, 1, 1}` while a more optimal solution of `{1, 4, 5}` exists.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang Thank you for explaining that to me! I couldn't quite put a finger on it.

Comment: Any ideas, I just finished the input, clueless on the algorithm tbh

Comment: @EmirGanovic Your assignment is for *you* to come up with an algorithm (possibly after spending hours thinking about different approaches and learning what does not work). SO is for specific coding issues. If you can come up with an attempt that fails, and identify where it fails, then maybe you'll have a suitable question for SO. (Of course, if you come up with an attempt that works, that's even better!)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hint rather than a real answer. No code; only math. Try to comprehend it, implement it with code, and let us know if your code doesn't work.

[image]
[image]

In your example, you would be especially interested in the value of `f(4, 72)`.

Comment: I am oddly confused, as the task states that it is mandatory using exactly one element from each group, and there can be n groups. However, i have a solution which I am posting right now, any optimization would be helpful.